# How to change html value and listeners configure in EXTJS BoxComponent

Tags: extjs, extjs3

My BoxComponent look like below

```
  this.terms = new Ext.BoxComponent({
     id: 'register_isv_terms_linkbox',
     itemId: 'register_isv_terms_link',
     autoEl: {
        id: 'register_isv_terms_link_el',
        tag: 'a',
        html: '',
        cls: 'ux-link'
      },
      listeners: {
           scope: this
      }
  });
  this.urls.add(this.terms);
```

i want to dynamically configure BoxComponent  `html` and `listeners(render)` inside some method. 
So i try look like below but this code not work for me

for html configure :-

```
 Ext.getCmp('register_isv_terms_linkbox').setHtml('www.google.com');
```

Anyone know how to dynamically configure BoxComponent please help to me

Comment: From the docs for ExtJS3, `BoxComponent` doesnt seem to have a `setHtml` method.

Comment: yes but how to set html for this BoxComponent

Comment: try this: Ext.getCmp('register_isv_terms_linkbox').html = "www.google.com";

Comment: sorry it's not work with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ext.getCmp('register_isv_terms_linkbox').update('www.google.com');

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are asking, sounds like you want to add some content when the box renders?

```
this.terms.on('render', function(box) {
    box.el.dom.innerHTML = 'Some Value';
}, this);
```

Not really sure what you are trying do with the listener, if you were more specific then it I'm sure the solution would be pretty strait forward. I'm kind of shooting the dark here though.